# Web Interface on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, python, nginx, web, raspberry-pi

I have a web application that I developed for use on a Raspberry Pi written in Python and hosted on nginx.  It's a bit slow to serve new pages, even when there is very little to no logic being processed for the page that's loading (4-5 seconds+).

I know that's a common problem as Pi's aren't exactly equipped to handle the load required to deliver web pages super quickly, but I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this and if it would be worthwhile to recreate the app in some other environment?  I was wondering if perhaps a nodejs server would be significantly (a few seconds) quicker in general, or building a single page application using react would be worthwhile? Or if there is some other solution that would be even faster?

EDIT:

more info: raspberry pi 3, json for storing/reading data (very small amounts of data), running chrome, only one user interacting directly with the app, and on the device itself (not from the internet or another network)

Comment: Which webserver do you use on the Pi? Or did you write it yourself?

Comment: I mean you can rent a vps for like 5/month...

Comment: using nginx. to vps: this isn't a web site people are going to connect to, this is an interface that only the user will interact with.

Comment: It's, of course, possible to run python webapplications on a Pi, there are numerous blogposts of people doing that. it's kinda to answer this without more information on a) what kind of pi, b) what kind of application(=database yes or no, filesystem access yes or no, how does nginx communicate with your backend, who accesses the site from where etc).

Comment: it shouldnt be slow ive served plenty of web applications ... are you using flask? cherrypy? django? etc?  i know for a fact flask works great (its probably the browser in rasbian... why not use the no graphics version and just connect over the network) at a guess its x11 stuff with rasbian

Comment: using flask, yeh. @JoranBeasley can you elaborate on the "no graphics version"?

Comment: I mean just expose it to the local intranet and then visit the url on a normal computer... I thought there was a server edition that didnt have the x11 stuff, but i could easily be wrong, it likely doesnt matter at a guess its plenty fast if accessed over a local network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the frontend will run on a browser executed on a laptop o desktop it will run fine, but if the interface will run on a browser executed on the Pi maybe it will be too expensive in terms of GPU/CPU usage and it will require fine tuning in order to avoid unnecessary re-renders.
So if the browser is on a remote machine ok, if not think about a something like TkInter for UI.